# Display table data as columns instead of rows in php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have multiple queries to a postgres database  to which i would like data to be returned. The data currently is being returned on several rows in two columns which is wrong. I woould like the data to be displayed in one row and several columns. The query is like this:

```
<?php

$sql = "Select ceil(SUM (a.CALLDURATION::integer) / 60) AS minutes,  sum(a.alltaxcost::integer) AS revenue
FROM cdr_data a,COUNTRY_CODES b
WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
     AND a.CALLCLASS = '008'
and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')

and not substr(a.zoneiddest,1,3) in ('254','255','211','257','250','256')
and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code)

union

select  ceil(sum(callduration::integer/60) )as    total_minutes,round(sum(alltaxcost::integer) ,2)as revenue
from cdr_data 
where callclass ='008' and callsubclass='001'
and callduration::integer >0
and  regexp_replace(callednumber,'^256','') ~ '^73'
and bundleunits = 'Money'
and regexp_replace(callednumber,'^256','') ~ '^73'

union

select ceil(sum(callduration::integer/60) )as  total_minutes,round(sum(alltaxcost::integer) ,2)as revenue
from cdr_data 
where callclass ='008' and callsubclass='001'
and callduration::integer >0
and  identifiant ~'^73'
and bundleunits = 'Money'
and zoneorange <> '-1'

union

SELECT sum(a.alltaxcost::integer) AS revenue, ceil(SUM (a.CALLDURATION::integer) / 60)  AS minutes
FROM cdr_data a,  COUNTRY_CODES b
WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
     AND a.CALLCLASS = '008'
and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')

and  substr(a.zoneiddest,1,3) in ('254','255','211','257','250')
and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code)
";


$result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
if (!$result) {
 die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }


  while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:15px' align='center'>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[8] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[10] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row[11] . "</td>";

 echo "</tr>";
    }
 // free memory
 pg_free_result($result);       

 // close connection
 pg_close($dbh);
 ?>
```

This displays my data as this:

```
International Minutes   International Revenue   Onnet Minutes   Onnet Revenue                        
      0                         0                                       
     1343                         578086
```

Which is not what i want. I would like the result to be like this

```
International Minutes   International Revenue   Onnet Minutes     Onnet Revenue                      
      0                         0              1343                  578086
```

So i want my results to be returned in one row and over 10 columns. How can i achieve this.

Comment: what data (format) you can get from DB?

Comment: how much record you have in table ?

Comment: the table has  the table headers which are split to display the columns and then one row where all the data has to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

So instead of doing a UNION, make each column it's own select statement.  Be aware that this is probably not very efficient.  Another option would be to insert into another table or view and then query off of that.

This is just an example but something like this:

```
$sql = "Select 
          (Select ceil(SUM (a.CALLDURATION::integer) / 60)       
          FROM cdr_data a,COUNTRY_CODES b
          WHERE  a.CALLSUBCLASS = '002'
          AND a.CALLCLASS = '008'
          and a.zoneiddest::integer > 0
          AND SUBSTR (a.CALLEDNUMBER, 1, 2) NOT IN
          ('77', '78', '75', '70', '71', '41', '31', '39', '76','79')
          and not substr(a.zoneiddest,1,3) in ('254','255','211','257','250','256')
          and trim(a.zoneiddest)  = trim(b.country_code) as International Minutes
         ,(Select ...
           from ...
           where ...) as International Revenue
         ,(Select ... 
           from ...
           where) as Onnet Minutes
         ,(Select ...
           from ...
           where ...) as Onnet Revenue
         FROM ...
         WHERE...
         ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , but you can try this.

```
 echo "<tr style='background-color: #FFFFFF;font-size:15px' align='center'>";

 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
    echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[8] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[10] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[11] . "</td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: No this doesnt help really as the data is displayed wrongly in columns  out of the ones i would it to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

There is postgresql extension named tablefunc which contains function **crosstab** doing exactly what you need. See the documentation page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html;

You need to install this extension first with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```